# How can i resize an image to a specified size?

Tags: perl, image-processing, imagemagick

Actually, i am shrinking high qualitiy images. I need to have one parameter (width or heigth) fixed and the other is flexible but with a defined minimum.
I want to keep the widht/height - ratio of the image.

**Example:**

I have an image (width x heigth) = 2000px x 3000px and i want it to shrink to a width of 968px and a minimum height of 640px while keeping the widht/height - ratio of the image.

**Using the imagemagick Perl API, what do i need to issue to shrink such an image?**

So far i have used this, but the results were only some white images:

```
        my $image = Image->new();
        $image->Read('my_2000x3000_image.jpg');
        $image = $image->[0];
        $image->Resize('geometry' => '968' . 'x' . '>');
        $image->Write('image_968_min_640.jpg');
```

Comment: Why do you do `$image = $image->[0];`? Also, what API are you using exactly? Everything I see uses `Image::Magick`, not `Image`.

Comment: What should happen if the minimum height constraint can't be met? For example, when processing a very wide image like 2000×1000px.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Image is an own wrapper class for Image::Magick

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image%3a%3aMagick) and the `Scale` method, which takes a maximum width and height

The following creates a thumbnail from an existing image:

```
# Thumbnail Dimensions
my ($max_height, $max_width) = (60,60);

my $thumbImage = new Image::Magick;
$thumbImage->Read($oldfile);
$thumbImage->Scale(geometry => qq{${max_height}x${max_width}}); 
$thumbImage->Write($newfile);
```

Comment: `Scale` uses pixel averaging which results in suboptimal quality. You should stick with `Resize`.

Comment: @nwellnhof That is an opinion.  Yes, it uses a different algorithm, but it's up the user to decide which is preferred.  For actual data discussing the difference: [`Scale - Minify with pixel averaging`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#scale).  The section _Scale Internals (pixel mixing)..._ discusses the difference specifically.

Comment: but i need to use a minimum height, how would i apply this?

Comment: Considering the aspect ratio of your orig image are `2000x3000`, reducing the height to a maximum of `968` will stay well above your minimum height of `640`.  Therefore setting maximum dimensions of `968x3000` should accomplish your goal in this case.

Comment: @Miller: it was just an example. if the original image would have dimensions 1936px x 1000px i would need to make sure the heigth wouldn't be below 640px